# Цикл while и логические операции

Tags: python

Почему неправильно работает данная конструкция?

```
while (a<b) and (a!=b):
    a=input('ddddd:')
    ...
print(a)
```

При этом происходит выход из цикла при значении `a == b`, а необходим выход из цикла строго при условии `a > b`

Если же заменить оператор `and` на `or`, тогда не происходит выхода из цикла даже при условии `a > b`

Comment: `while условие` - будет выполняться пока условие True у вас же оно False когда a == b. Проще всего будет сделать `while not (a > b):`

Comment: @gord1402, ещё проще будет `while a <= b:`.

Comment: @wchistow да действительно как-то забыл.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну так именно такая логика и задана. Если `a==b`, то второе условие `False,` значит, и всё условие в целом `True and False = False`

Вам же достаточно одного такого условия:

```
while (a<=b):
```

Comment: О! Точно же! Спасибо!

Comment: А ещё можно без скобок.